# What different when writing to file opened be "t" or "b" in any code language?

Tags: c++

The code isnt importent here, because I want to understand the exact idea of what happening when writing characters to binary opened mode with regard to opening it by textual mode?

I tried to do the next thing:

```
file.open("muzic.mp3", std::ios::binary);
```

Which is opening a muzic file in a binary mode and then writing characters I took from another song.
The song I wrote - worked well...

But if I do the next thing:

```
file.open("muzic.mp3");
```

Which opening it in textual mode - so I will hear just noises when I will open the new song I wrote.

So what exactly happening when I use each mode? What is making the difference between the two same characters chunks writing in a different mode?

Comment: The suggested duplicate is not duplicate because it is exactly the same question, but I think the accepted answer is a sufficient answer for this question as well :)

Answer (score 0):

The difference between opening a file in text mode and binary mode is that certain control characters, particularly line-feeds may be subject to special processing. For example, if you open a file for output on windows and write a line-feed character via `'\n'`, then in text mode the linefeed  will be expanded to the carriage-return/line-feed pair which Windows programs like to see at the end of lines. On a Linux system, nothing would be changed, and in general text and binary mode works the same on Linux systems. In no case does using binary mode magically change the output into a different format, line endings asside.